# Probability of sub-sequence of exact length to occur

Tags: pr.probability, sequences-and-series

Let's suppose that I have a sequence of length $L$ of uniformly distributed random numbers on interval $(a,b)$. How can I calculate probability that increasing sub-sequence of length $M,M <L, $ will occur?

Comment: Is $(a, b)$ an interval of reals or something else?

Comment: You seem to be asking for the probablity that a continuous random variable takes a particular value. If that is not what you meant, could you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that it's about **increasing** sub-sequences. I edited now. Yes, $a,b\in R$.

Comment: Ah, right, now this makes more sense. But presumably you can WLOG take $a=0, b=1$?

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes, of course, it can be interval $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Equivalently, you may count the probability of an increasing sub-sequence of length $M$ in a random permutation of $1,2,\dots,L$.

To determine this probability, it is enough to know the number of $L$-permutations avoiding an increasing pattern of length $M+1$. For $M=1$, there is just one such $L$-permutation. For $M=2$, these permutations are counted by Catalan numbers. For $M=3$, see the [OEIS sequence A005802](https://oeis.org/A005802).

For general fixed $M$, asymptotic formulas were computed by [Regev](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870881900128), see also [this paper by Bóna](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316598929089). Very roughly, the number of $L$-permutations with no increasing subsequence of length $M+1$ is $(2M)^L$ up to a polynomial factor in $L$.